# How to process a JSON array with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk, logstash-json

I'm writing a Logstash pipeline to inject log files in JSON format.
Some of these input files contain records with a nested JSON arrays.
This pipeline needs to index each of the JSON objects within such array into an Elasticsearch index. The name of tis ES index will depend on the value of the "companyName" field in each JSON object.
So far I am able to process individual JSON objects, but not the arrays.
Here is an example of my input log file:

```
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users","Context":"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:18","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:18","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"userId\":433157,\"companyId\":343,\"userGuid\":\"B05DE331A3F540AB8748\",\"username\":\"Thu Huynh\",\"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":0,\"eaHierarchyId\":0,\"timeZone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\",\"timeZoneIANA\":null,\"timeZoneDisplayName\":null,\"currentLocationId\":540132,\"currentNodeId\":543116,\"currentModelId\":13022,\"userTypeId\":4,\"emailAddress\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\",\"openId\":null,\"accountId\":0,\"isSuperAdmin\":0,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false},{\"userId\":433177,\"companyId\":345,\"userGuid\":\"8B89A34960AE4778B8B8\",\"username\":\"THuynh\",\"companyName\":\"Sphera Energy\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":0,\"eaHierarchyId\":0,\"timeZone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\",\"timeZoneIANA\":null,\"timeZoneDisplayName\":null,\"currentLocationId\":527117,\"currentNodeId\":530114,\"currentModelId\":11706,\"userTypeId\":1,\"emailAddress\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\",\"openId\":null,\"accountId\":0,\"isSuperAdmin\":0,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/locations/540132/roles","Context":"Admin GetFilteredUserRolesByLocation","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\",\"locationId\":\"540132\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:25","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:25","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[\"EA_MGR_DASHBOARD_FULL\"]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenessnodetypes","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenessNodeTypes","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:26","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:26","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"nodeTypeId\":106026,\"nodeTypeName\":\"[TL] - Node Type B\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105467,\"nodeTypeName\":\"A1\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105444,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Asset\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105448,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Boiler\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105447,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Boiler_X\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105452,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Boiler-Heater\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105449,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Emergency Power\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105450,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Turbine\"}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/lastupdate","Context":"Dashboard LastUpdate","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:27","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:27","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"\"2023-09-05T10:22:33.167Z\"","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/doclinkscard/","Context":"Dashboard Get","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:27","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:27","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"items\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"take\":5}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/emission","Context":"Dashboard Emission","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:27","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:27","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenessparametersets","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenessParameterSets","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:28","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:28","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"parameterSetId\":65747,\"parameterSetName\":\"Operating\"}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/doclinkscard/","Context":"Dashboard Get","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:28","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:28","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"items\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"take\":5}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenesses","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenesses","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:28","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:28","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"periodicityType\":5,\"data\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"top\":5,\"order\":1,\"contains\":\"\"}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenesses","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenesses","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:29","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:29","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"periodicityType\":5,\"data\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"top\":5,\"order\":1,\"contains\":\"\"}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/locations/540132/roles","Context":"Admin GetFilteredUserRolesByLocation","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\",\"locationId\":\"540132\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:34","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:34","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[\"EA_DATA_ENTRY_TEMPLATES\",\"EA_DATA_ENTRY_TEMPLATES_FULL\",\"EA_DATA_ENTRY_TEMPLATES_DELETE\"]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"433157","Username":"Thu Huynh","Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com","Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/locations/540132/roles","Context":"Admin GetFilteredUserRolesByLocation","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"433157\",\"moduleId\":\"1\",\"locationId\":\"540132\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:39","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:39","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[\"EA_DATA_ENTRY_TEMPLATES_FULL\"]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":null,"Username":null,"Email":null,"Timezone":null,"CompanyId":null,"Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/users/authenticate","Context":"Admin AuthenticateUser","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"\",\"userId\":\"\",\"moduleId\":\"\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:47","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:47","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"userId\":432929,\"companyId\":343,\"userGuid\":\"DC2365012ADA44629B0B\",\"username\":\"QA Implementer\",\"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":1493,\"eaHierarchyId\":1493,\"timeZone\":\"Dateline Standard Time\",\"timeZoneIANA\":\"Etc/GMT+12\",\"timeZoneDisplayName\":\"(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West\",\"currentLocationId\":527197,\"currentNodeId\":530191,\"currentModelId\":13005,\"userTypeId\":4,\"emailAddress\":\"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com\",\"openId\":\"d435d135-3400-4e66-ae6b-fd12cd47e618\",\"accountId\":3,\"isSuperAdmin\":1,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":null,"Username":null,"Email":null,"Timezone":null,"CompanyId":null,"Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/users/authenticate","Context":"Admin AuthenticateUser","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"\",\"userId\":\"\",\"moduleId\":\"\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:47","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:47","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"userId\":432929,\"companyId\":343,\"userGuid\":\"DC2365012ADA44629B0B\",\"username\":\"QA Implementer\",\"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":1493,\"eaHierarchyId\":1493,\"timeZone\":\"Dateline Standard Time\",\"timeZoneIANA\":\"Etc/GMT+12\",\"timeZoneDisplayName\":\"(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West\",\"currentLocationId\":527197,\"currentNodeId\":530191,\"currentModelId\":13005,\"userTypeId\":4,\"emailAddress\":\"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com\",\"openId\":\"d435d135-3400-4e66-ae6b-fd12cd47e618\",\"accountId\":3,\"isSuperAdmin\":1,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users","Context":"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:50","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:50","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"userId\":433209,\"companyId\":314,\"userGuid\":\"2596A94F40144919A7A5\",\"username\":\"QA Implementer\",\"companyName\":\"Sphera Enterprise Demo\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":0,\"eaHierarchyId\":0,\"timeZone\":null,\"timeZoneIANA\":null,\"timeZoneDisplayName\":null,\"currentLocationId\":0,\"currentNodeId\":0,\"currentModelId\":0,\"userTypeId\":4,\"emailAddress\":\"spheracloudeaqa@gmail.com\",\"openId\":null,\"accountId\":0,\"isSuperAdmin\":0,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false},{\"userId\":432929,\"companyId\":343,\"userGuid\":\"DC2365012ADA44629B0B\",\"username\":\"QA Implementer\",\"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":0,\"eaHierarchyId\":0,\"timeZone\":\"Dateline Standard Time\",\"timeZoneIANA\":null,\"timeZoneDisplayName\":null,\"currentLocationId\":527197,\"currentNodeId\":530191,\"currentModelId\":13005,\"userTypeId\":4,\"emailAddress\":\"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com\",\"openId\":null,\"accountId\":0,\"isSuperAdmin\":0,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false},{\"userId\":433210,\"companyId\":344,\"userGuid\":\"116F130D455243F0974C\",\"username\":\"QA Implementer\",\"companyName\":\"EA QA2\",\"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\",\"currentHierarchyId\":0,\"eaHierarchyId\":0,\"timeZone\":null,\"timeZoneIANA\":null,\"timeZoneDisplayName\":null,\"currentLocationId\":0,\"currentNodeId\":0,\"currentModelId\":0,\"userTypeId\":4,\"emailAddress\":\"spheracloudeaqa@gmail.com\",\"openId\":null,\"accountId\":0,\"isSuperAdmin\":0,\"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/locations/527197/roles","Context":"Admin GetFilteredUserRolesByLocation","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\",\"locationId\":\"527197\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:51","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:51","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[\"EA_MGR_DASHBOARD_FULL\"]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenessnodetypes","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenessNodeTypes","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"nodeTypeId\":106026,\"nodeTypeName\":\"[TL] - Node Type B\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105467,\"nodeTypeName\":\"A1\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105444,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Asset\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105448,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Boiler\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105447,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Boiler_X\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105452,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Boiler-Heater\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105449,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Emergency Power\"},{\"nodeTypeId\":105450,\"nodeTypeName\":\"Turbine\"}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/emission","Context":"Dashboard Emission","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Jan\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Feb\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Mar\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Apr\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"May\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Jun\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Jul\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Aug\",\"values\":[{\"value\":10.0,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/lastupdate","Context":"Dashboard LastUpdate","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"\"2023-09-05T10:22:33.167Z\"","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/doclinkscard/","Context":"Dashboard Get","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"items\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"take\":5}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenessparametersets","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenessParameterSets","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:52","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"parameterSetId\":65747,\"parameterSetName\":\"Operating\"}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/emission","Context":"Dashboard Emission","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"[{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Jan\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Feb\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Mar\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Apr\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"May\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Jun\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Jul\",\"values\":[{\"value\":null,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]},{\"parameterId\":562280,\"year\":2023,\"month\":\"Aug\",\"values\":[{\"value\":10.0,\"uomId\":297586,\"difference\":0.0}]}]","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/doclinkscard/","Context":"Dashboard Get","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"items\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"take\":5}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenesses","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenesses","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"periodicityType\":5,\"data\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"top\":5,\"order\":1,\"contains\":\"\"}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
{"UserId":"432929","Username":"QA Implementer","Email":"SpheraCloudEAQA@gmail.com","Timezone":"Dateline Standard Time","CompanyId":"343","Operation":"POST","Channel":"UI","Path":"/api/v1.0/dashboard/datacollectioncompletenesses","Context":"Dashboard DataCollectionCompletenesses","Params":"{\"companyId\":\"343\",\"userId\":\"432929\",\"moduleId\":\"1\"}","Object":"","EventType":"Field Value Change","DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:23:53","ModifiedDate":"","ResponseCode":"200","ResponseMessage":"{\"periodicityType\":5,\"data\":[],\"pageInfo\":{\"totalCount\":0,\"skip\":0,\"top\":5,\"order\":1,\"contains\":\"\"}}","PreviousValue":"","NewValue":""}
```

In this file each record contains the "ResoinseMessage" field which is the JSON array that I need to be able to process.

Here is my current Logstash pipeline:

```
input {
# Read JSON files from the /logs/json/ directory
  file {
    path => "/logs/json/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
    # remove this for not always starting from the beginning of the file
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => "json"
    type => "json"
    mode => "tail"
  }
}

filter {
    # Parse JSON data
    json {
      source => "message"
    }

    split {
    field => "[ResponseMessage]"
  }
    
  mutate {
     add_field => {
    "company_name" => "%{[ResponseMessage][companyName]}"
  }
       }
   mutate {
    lowercase => [company_name]
  }
}


output {
  if [company_name] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "https://elasticsearch:9200" ]
      index => "log_data_%{[company_name]}"
      ssl => true
      cacert => "/usr/share/logstash/config/ca.crt"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
    }
  }
  # Send data to stdout
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

As you can tell, I am attempting to split the "ResponseMessage", but so far I'm not seeing ES indexes being created as intended.

What can I improve in this pipeline to effectively split each "ResponseMessage" and index individual JSON objects into ES?